# Mongo Db Random Timeout when reading from Java Driver - Can't call something

Tags: java, mongodb

I have an application that is finding one document from Mongo DB when a client is trying to login. While this works most of the times, it sometimes throws a timeout underneath  "com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : ..."

Once a request fails (after the preconfigured timeout), the next request seems to work fine but then some other call randomly fails with the same exception. The relevant part of the stack trace is

```
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:295)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:727)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:669)
```

I'm using Spring's MongoTemplate to get a collection and then query it for finding a single document. My Code Snippet would be something like that shown below

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("myIntParam", 283);
DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection(collectionName);
DBObject foundDocument = collection.findOne(query);
```

Same mongo template instance is getting used in the application for other reading and writing purposes in different collections (I think it is recommended to use only a single instance per app).

The problem usually comes after I leave the application idle for some time. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.10 server (my local env has desktop version for Ubuntu 12.10) with JDK 1.7 from within tomcat. Java Driver Version is 2.10.1. Following configuration options are supplied

```
mongoOptions.connectTimeout=5000
mongoOptions.socketTimeout=60000
mongoOptions.socketKeepAlive=true
mongoOptions.maxWaitTime=15000
mongoOptions.autoConnectRetry=true
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `mongoOptions.socketTimeout=60000` item, or catch the timeout exception then handle it by yourself.

Comment: Removing socketTimeout results in the call blocking - If I'm not mistaken the default value for timeout is infinite which results in my call getting blocked for ever in this scenario. I suspect that my connection to the server is getting lost somehow (maybe connectivity issue) - but is there a way to figure out the health of the connection before making the call (ideally I would want the driver to reconnect automatically in case the connection is stale)